# Celery Worker Error : self.buffer = mmap.mmap(self.fd, self.size) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker

I am getting self.buffer = mmap.mmap(self.fd, self.size) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory error while running celery with docker on windows. It is working perfectly on mac.

```html
dvu-celeryworker    | [2021-03-26 11:08:20,286: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
dvu-celeryworker    | Traceback (most recent call last):
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 208, in start
dvu-celeryworker    |     self.blueprint.start(self)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
dvu-celeryworker    |     step.start(parent)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 369, in start
dvu-celeryworker    |     return self.obj.start()
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/concurrency/base.py", line 132, in start
dvu-celeryworker    |     self.on_start()
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/concurrency/prefork.py", line 111, in on_start
dvu-celeryworker    |     P = self._pool = Pool(processes=self.limit,
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py", line 486, in __init__
dvu-celeryworker    |     super(AsynPool, self).__init__(processes, *args, **kwargs)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1046, in __init__
dvu-celeryworker    |     self._create_worker_process(i)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py", line 503, in _create_worker_process
dvu-celeryworker    |     return super(AsynPool, self)._create_worker_process(i)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1142, in _create_worker_process
dvu-celeryworker    |     on_ready_counter = self._ctx.Value('i')
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/context.py", line 181, in Value
dvu-celeryworker    |     return Value(typecode_or_type, *args, lock=lock,
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/sharedctypes.py", line 78, in Value
dvu-celeryworker    |     obj = RawValue(typecode_or_type, *args)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/sharedctypes.py", line 46, in RawValue
dvu-celeryworker    |     obj = _new_value(type_)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/sharedctypes.py", line 37, in _new_value
dvu-celeryworker    |     wrapper = heap.BufferWrapper(size)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/heap.py", line 274, in __init__
dvu-celeryworker    |     block = BufferWrapper._heap.malloc(size)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/heap.py", line 255, in malloc
dvu-celeryworker    |     (arena, start, stop) = self._malloc(size)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/heap.py", line 152, in _malloc
dvu-celeryworker    |     arena = Arena(length)
dvu-celeryworker    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/billiard/heap.py", line 104, in __init__
dvu-celeryworker    |     self.buffer = mmap.mmap(self.fd, self.size)
dvu-celeryworker    | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please help.

Comment: Please provide more info. How is your container launched? Add the docker-compose.yml content to your question if any.

Comment: Hello, is it possible that we can connect over meet ? i'll show you every configuration.